# How do I get a Joomla user id (which is a number) from user name?

Tags: joomla

I would like to get the Joomla user Id from the user name, I will be using this in an external script.

Comment: Usually you have to write a special query for that.  Most systems expect you to already know the user id, because the user had to log in and it handed you a user id when they logged in.

Comment: You question is VERY vague. There're several ways of getting user ID depending of given task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you don't want to get it via Joomla, just use a SQL statement like this:

```
SELECT id FROM #__users WHERE username = 'someusername';
```

Or load Joomla and use something like this code:

```
if (!defined('_JEXEC')) {
    define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
    define ('JPATH_BASE', "c:\\wamp\\www\\oursite");
    define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
    require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
    require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );
    require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'libraries'.DS.'joomla'.DS.'factory.php' );
    require_once ( JPATH_LIBRARIES.DS.'joomla'.DS.'import.php'); // Joomla library imports.
    $app=& JFactory::getApplication('site');
}

$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('id');
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__users'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('username')." = ".$db->quote('someusername'));
$db->setQuery($query);
$user_id = $db->loadResult();

// Get a JUser object, if you want/need it
$user = JFactory::getUser($user_id);
```